# Adding system tools to custom toolbox in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, toolbox, geoprocessing-framework

I am still getting over the quirks of ArcGIS Pro, right now I want to create my own toolbox that contains some tools useful for my current project: hillshade, contour and kernel density.

But it seems to me that there is no way to add system tools to a custom toolbox.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The Help page to read on this is [Save a custom set of geoprocessing tools](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/save-geoprocessing-tools-in-your-project.htm) and I think the key sentence that answers your question is:

> You cannot add system tools to a project toolbox; only custom script
>   and model tools that you build can be added.

Alternative workflows are described there and summarized here:

> You can save a custom set of geoprocessing tools within an ArcGIS
>   project so the most important tasks of your project can be quickly and
>   easily completed. The set of tools you save in a project can contain
>   both ArcGIS tools and custom tools that you have built or that others
>   have shared with you.

and

> You can use a project template to import a set of tools from one
>   project to your current project or to a new project, or if you want to
>   always have the same custom sets of tools regardless of your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. "You cannot add system tools to a project toolbox", this seems like a foolish downgrade to me. Custom toolbox is a great boost for quality of life in GIS IMHO. What if I create the toolbox in Arcmap and try to import it into Pro?  And how shall I "save a custom set of geoprocessing tools within an ArcGIS project"? Shall I do it in the catalog or just add them as favorite?

Comment: You could test creating a custom toolbox with system tools in ArcMap and importing it into ArcGIS Pro. I think that help page is talking about favorites but I have only had a quick read and have not had a chance to test.

Comment: Thanks. I will get a chance to test it next week or this weekend.